# Fiserv/OSI DNA and ACH Origination job

Tags: job-scheduling, payment-processing, banking, job-queue, core-banking

Is anyone here familiar with the Fiserv (formerly Open Solutions) DNA banking platform? I'm looking for a second opinion on ACH origination as we're having problems with how the job is running.

The problem we are having is with regards to the timing of when payments posts on our system, specifically loan payments. What happens is the origination file will generate to be sent to the Fed on the day the payment is due however however the on us side comes through a day later instead of the day it was set for.

I'm not thinking this is related to the Fed Days as we've tried running our ACHC/ACHD settings both at 2/1 and 1/1 and run into the same issue both ways, which to me indicates this may be related to the order in which the AH_ORIG and the MM_SALOT/MM_IALOT jobs run.

I do know that the MM_SALOT and the MM_IALOT jobs run the night before the AH_ORIG job is run. The AH_ORIG job runs in the morning during normal ACH Exception processing.

I also noticed that on our ACH Origination report that the loan side of the transaction comes through as XPMT almost like a loan payment that was generated at another institution and coming in to us.  The documentation I have indicates that the withdrawal side of transactions we originate should show as XWTH (which they do) and loan allocations should show as LPMT (which they aren't).

My questions are:
1) What should our Fed days be set at? We process allocations 7 days a week and the documentarian states that ACHC and ACHD should be set at 1/1.
2) What order should the AH_ORIG and MM_SALOT and the MM_IALOT jobs be run in and when should they be run?

If anybody could help me out with this that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a Compass Case with Fiserv. They provide support and can advise you on the proper way those jobs should function.

https://compass.opensolutions.com/psp/crmprod/CUSTOMER/CRM/s/WEBLIB_PTPP_SC.HOMEPAGE.FieldFormula.IScript_AppHP?pt_fname=CR_RC_CUST_CARE&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.CR_RC_CUST_CARE&IsFolder=true&